# How to make the border of the password input field red when password is wrong?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, border

I am making a login screen, where i want the border of the password input field to turn red when the password is incorrect. With the use of HTML, CSS and PHP inside of Laravel. It already gives a error when the password is incorrect. Can somebody please help? I don't know if its necessary but here is what i have in my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
    body{
        background-color: #ccffcc;
        
        }


#container
{

    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 450px;
    height: 250px;
    margin-left: 650px;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 15px solid #0d0d0d;
    padding: 50px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    background-color: white;

}


h5
{
    width: 450px;
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-left: 115px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    line-height: 0px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    font-family: Georgia;

}

.Button1
{
    width: 120px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 360px;
    left: 860px;

}

.Button2
{

    height: auto;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 515px;
    left: 1100px;

}
button
{
    height: 40px;
    width: 110px;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #0066ff;
    font-family: Courier New monospace;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}

input
{
    font-size: 21px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -105px;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    
}

.passw
{
    font-size: 21px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 280px;
    left: 758px;
    font-family: Cambria;


}

::placeholder 
{
    font-size: 15px;
}


button:hover {background-color:#0052cc;}

.error
{
    
    color: red;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 800px;
    top: 452px;
    font-family: Cambria;
}

</style>

<div id="container">

    <h5>Login</h5>

</div>

<div class="error">
@if($errors->any())
  <h4>{{$errors->first()}}</h4>
@endif
</div>

    <div class="Button2">
        <form action="/auth" method="post">
        @csrf
            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Log in</button> 
        </form>
    </div>



    <div class="passw">Wachtwoord :</div>
        <div class="Button1">
            <input type="password"

            name= "wachtwoord" 
            placeholder="Max 4 numbers"
            maxlength="4">
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know there are some things wrong, i changed it up a little. Forgive me.

and this is my controller:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{


    public function verification(Request $request)
    {

        if ($request->post('wachtwoord') == '1507')
        { 
          \Session::put('ingelogd', 'yes');
          return redirect()->intended('/welcomescreen');
        }

        else
        {
          \Session::put('ingelogd', 'no');
          return redirect()->intended('/')->withErrors(['wachtwoord'=> 'Password incorrect, Try again']);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your code and attempt?

Comment: "I want" isn't a question. And [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) either. See also [ask]. It's unclear where/how/why you're stuck. The methods of adding colour HTML elements isn't a secret, you can google that easily.

Comment: Work out what HTML/CSS you need, and then work out what PHP (or JS, if the validation is done client-side) you'd need in your view code in order to set that. Ask us again if you actually get stuck and provide a [mre] of the issue. We're not a substitute for basic research / effort. We're an encyclopaedia, not a free helpdesk or coding service - if a task has been done before, and we already have a question about it, or it's trivial to find from existing documentation and tutorials, we don't need another one. See also the [tour].

Comment: `@if($errors->any())
  <h4>{{$errors->first()}}</h4>
@endif`...why do you only show the first error? Why not all of them? And what's in `$errors`? Does it contain a map of the field names and the error messages?  If so, you can use that to decide where to display each error and/or whether to apply a colour change to any specific elements. If it doesn't, then getting your error data into a format where you can use it to decide what to do is likely to be your first step.

Comment: I made the error message in my controller.  I know how to make a border red, i just don't know how to make sure it goes to red when the password is wrong and where to do it.

Comment: Well, the precise approach to that depends on what I wrote in my last comment, which you haven't replied to.

Comment: You can [edit] your post if you want to add more code etc

Comment: I added my controller

Comment: Ok so you have an array (`['wachtwoord'=> 'Password incorrect, Try again']`) with a key, so that seems good. Therefore you should be able to check to see if the `wachtwoord` element exists in the errors array, and if so, set an extra class or style attribute on the password textbox element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="phone" onkeyup="checkPassword()" />
```

And also make checkPassword function

```
function CheckPassword(inputtxt) 
{ 
    var passw=  /^[A-Za-z]\w{7,14}$/;
    if(inputtxt.value.match(passw)) 
    { 
       alert('Correct, try another...')
       return true;
    }
    else
    { 
       alert('Wrong...!')
       return false;
    }
}
```